# Can I get the current class type id from a static base method?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

Is there anyway to get a type from a static base class method? For instance

```
class A
{
    static std::type_info getClassType
    {
        // What do I do here
    }
};

class B : public A
{

};

B instance;
auto my_type = instance::getClassType()
```

With C++'s lack of static variable overloading, I am having a hard time figuring out a way to determine class type across classes without doing a special virtual function in every child class which I am trying to avoid due to the sheer number.

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: Search  "C++ CRTP"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hard to explain it all, but it boils down to there being a manager class that keeps track of one instance of a variety of classes and their states. You may use this singleton "instance" of these sub classes, but I want to be able to say MySubClass::instance() and then have it get the correct instance from the manager without having to write it in each sub class. Basically, I could do it the hard way, but I feel it should be possible to do within the base class and want to know if its possible. I am aware of many ways to write more code and get it done though.

Comment: `instance.getClassType()` is syntaxic sugar equivalent to `A::getClassType()`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo

Comment: @Jarod42 Btw, the problem is that I don't have an instance and I am using this static method to create an instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class that will be a template.
Subclass from it. Pass the child type as the template parameter.
With that, base class will know the child. The `T` will be the child type.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> class thebase
{
  static T instance;
public:
  static T& getInstance() { return instance; }
};

template <typename T> T thebase<T>::instance;

class sub1 : public thebase<sub1> {
public: void tell() { std::cout << "hello1: " << this << std::endl; }
};

class sub2 : public thebase<sub2> {
public: void tell() { std::cout << "hello2: " << this << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  sub1& ref1 = sub1::getInstance();
  sub1& ref2 = sub1::getInstance();
  std::cout << ((&ref1) == (&ref2)) << std::endl;
  sub1::getInstance().tell();
  sub2::getInstance().tell();
  sub1::getInstance().tell();
  sub2::getInstance().tell();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
hello1: 0x55874bff1193
hello2: 0x55874bff1192
hello1: 0x55874bff1193
hello2: 0x55874bff1192
```

This kind of code pattern is sometimes called [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: and yup, I forgot the typeinfo, but since it's possible to declare `static T instance;` then the type is known statically, so typeinfo has to work as well.

Comment: I immediately suggested CRTP in the commets to the Question. I was fiddling around trying to make `getClassType` return a `const type_info&` when you posted this. That's what the OP wanted, not a `tell()`. I think I'll let you work it out.

Answer (score 2):

> it boils down to there being a manager class that keeps track of one instance of a variety of classes and their states. You may use this singleton "instance" of these sub classes, but I want to be able to say MySubClass::instance() and then have it get the correct instance from the manager without having to write it in each sub class.

You can implement the managed classes using [CRTP ("Curiously recurring template pattern")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/) so a base class knows the derived class types and can then delegate that information to the manager class.

Try something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Manager
{
private:
    static std::map<std::type_index, Base*> m_instances;

public:
    template<typename T>
    static void addInstance(Base *inst) {
        if (!m_instances.insert(std::make_pair(std::type_index(typeid(T)), inst)).second)
            throw ...; // only 1 instance allowed at a time!
    }

    template<typename T>
    static void removeInstance() {
        auto iter = m_instances.find(std::type_index(typeid(T)));
        if (iter != m_instances.end())
            m_instances.erase(iter);
    }

    template<typename T>
    static T* getInstance() {        
        auto iter = m_instances.find(std::type_index(typeid(T)));
        if (iter != m_instances.end())
            return static_cast<T*>(iter->second);
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

```
std::map<std::type_index, Base*> Manager::m_instances;
```

```
template<class Derived>
class A : public Base
{
public:
    A() {
        Manager::addInstance<Derived>(this);
    }

    ~A() {
        Manager::removeInstance<Derived>();
    }

    static Derived* getInstance() {
        return Manager::getInstance<Derived>();
    }
};

class B : public A<B>
{
    ...
};

class C : public A<C>
{
    ...
};
```

```
B b_inst;
C c_inst;

...

B *pB = B::getInstance();
if (pB) ...

C *pC = C::getInstance();
if (pC) ...
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/3Y1EF2)

Comment: I don't see the definition of `getClassType`, which is all that the OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your own example of code in your own answer, here's a final result working:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <typeinfo>

template <class T> 
class A
{
public:
    static const std::type_info& getClassType()
    {
        return typeid(T);
    }
};

class B : public A<B>
{ /* ... */ };

class C : public A<C>
{ /* ... */};

class D : public A<D>
{ /* ... */};

int main()
{
    B b; C c; D d;
    auto& b_type = b.getClassType();
    auto& c_type = c.getClassType();
    auto& d_type = d.getClassType();

    std::cout << b_type.name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << c_type.name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << d_type.name() << std::endl;
}
```

> Output: 
>   1B 1C 1D

Answer (score 0):

Someone above mentioned the CRTP or "Curiously recurring template pattern". Using this, I have not tested it, but it appears I may be able to write:

```
template <class T> 
class A
{
    static std::type_info getClassType
    {
        return typeid(T);
    }
};


class B : public A<B>
{

};

B instance;
auto my_type = instance::getClassType()
```